# Errors with StatefulService

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When I try to debug the simple HelloWorldStateful service, I get the following errors:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in
>   mscorlib.dll Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Log.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.ArgumentException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Log.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Log.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Fabric.dll

I can run stateless services and both types of actors fine.   But the stateful services just do not want to work for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far to solve your problem? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I have run the health status on the service and got the following error:  Replica had multiple failures during open. Error = -2147024894, that lead me to turn on tracking System.IO.Exceptions in the debugger, which gave me the stacktrace above.  Also, I have 200GB on my harddrive, so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6ca0527a-8aa7-44e4-bca2-7087f217a434/problem-deploying-helloworldstateful-stateful-service?forum=AzureServiceFabric

"By default the installation installs service fabric to C:\SfDevCluster.

I had a similar problem when I installed service fabric to a non-default drive & folder.  Only stateful services (not actors) failed.  Debugging and breaking on exceptions did not help.

Worked fine when I left the install to its defaults.

I am not sure if that was the root cause, but things worked fine afterwards.  Worth a try.  Hope this helps.
"

Did this work for you?